# How to syntax-highlight function arguments inside function in Sublime?

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting, textmate, sublimetext

I would like to highlight the arguments of a Ruby function in Sublime, when they are used inside the function. Like so:

```
def my_func(arg1, arg2 = nil)
  puts arg1 # should be highlighted
  puts arg2 # should be highlighted
end
```

I've been messing with Sublime's plist syntax highlighting format for a while (same as Textmate's), but having trouble figuring out how to capture one group (the args in the def line) and use them to match more expressions in another group (the whole method)

I have seen `\1` and `\2` being used in `EndCapture` groups before, which gives me hope that this is possible, for example by using `\1` in a `match` group. But I just can't seem to get it to work. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Try this app: http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#/theme/Monokai

Answer (score 0):

(too long for comment)

If writing regexes in XML/PLIST is driving you batty, try installing the [`PackageDev`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageDev) plugin via Package Control. There is an option to convert PLIST `.tmLanguage` syntax files to YAML, and when you're done editing you can convert it back to PLIST. This way, you don't have to mess around with trying to get all the `<dict><array><whatever>` tags correct in the `.tmLanguage` file, and you can focus on the regexes, capturing groups, etc. It also uses the Oniguruma syntax, which I assume you're at least somewhat familiar with if you're a Rubyist. I maintain an [improved syntax](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PythonImproved) for Python, and my work has been so much easier since I started using the `.YAML-tmlanguage` format.

Good luck!